# "sidebar" seems to be attached to "main," but i'm unsure how/how to undo

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I'm designing a blog/portfolio with three sections- header/nav is on the far left, the main content is in the vertical center, and the sidebar is on the far right. My intention is to have the header/nav in a fixed position on the left, and the sidebar in a fixed position on the right, with the main content scrolling through the vertical center.

I noticed that when I began work on the portfolio page(again, aligned with the vertical center), thus removing the main content, the sidebar moved from it's supposedly fixed position to the far left near the header/nav.

I'm having a hard time finding exactly what's causing this and I don't quite know how to ensure that the sidebar with stay to the far right regardless of what is (or isn't) in the center.

```
<body>
    <header>
        <logo>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="whskytngfxtrt logo" height="139" width="158" /></a>
        </logo><!-- end logo -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="blog"><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                <li id="work"><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
                <li id="about"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav><!-- end nav -->
    </header><!-- end header -->

    <work>
        <category>
            <ul>
                <h1>Web</h1>

                <h1>Print</h1>

                <h1>Identity</h1>
            </ul>

    <sidebar>
        <dictionary>
            <h3><b>hwis-kee tang-goh foks-trot</b></h3>
            <h4><p><i>noun</i> 1. the best damn creative studio there ever was</p></h4>
        </dictionary><!-- end dictionary -->

        <twitter>
            <h3>@whskytngfxtrt</h3>
            <h4><ul>
                <li><a href="#">sometimes i just really love the internet</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sometimes i just really love the internet</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sometimes i just really love the internet</a></li>
            </ul></h4>
        </twitter><!-- end twitter -->

header {
    background: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 123px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 158px; 
}
main {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: 310px;
}
work {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: 310px;  
}
sidebar {
    border-top: 1px solid #202020;
    padding-top: 25px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 153px;
    margin-top: 295px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 158px;
}
sidebar dictionary {
    position: fixed;
}

sidebar twitter {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Is this actually your code or just a snippet? It looks, like the nesting inside is not correct.

Comment: I find your colorful language describing your studio both offensive, and non-professional. I would appreciate it very much if you would edit it. If you do, feel free to delete this comment. Thanks!

Comment: @yunzen- could you elaborate? working primarily in print, i'm still fairly new to this.

Comment: @samstar- thank you for your concern. however, i see no harm in interjecting a touch of humor in an otherwise very simple site. as for the language, i find it hard to believe that "damn" will be the worst thing you read today.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Sounds like you need some `left:?px`.</strike>

<strike>i.e. #sidebar {left:800px;}</strike>

<strike>As to what is causing that, if I understand the problem correctly, all that is happening is the `position:fixed`
is taking the sidebar out of the document flow, and since it is out of the document flow, it positions itself
against the browser window, or the next `position:fixed` element. This is a normal function of `position:fixed`, and is fixed by using `left, right, top, bottom,` and if all else fails, `margin and padding`.</strike>

Edit

Try this code replacing your sidebar styles:

```
sidebar {
border-top: 1px solid #202020;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 153px;
margin-top: 295px;
padding-top: 25px;
position: fixed;
width: 158px;
```

Floats don't work with `position:fixed`. 
This fixed it for me... But I still can't see the logo. Judging by your url, It looks like the `img` is in a file on your computer, and is inaccessible to the actual web.

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your help. In changing position:fixed to position:right, on the index.html (or main) page, the 'sidebar dictionary' and 'sidebar twitter' elements stay in place while the border moves along with the main content. On the work.html page, the sidebar elements are sent to the bottom of the page, though still appear to move in conjunction with the 'work' content.

I feel this is possibly issue of nesting, as @yunzen suggested, though I'm unsure of how to pinpoint exactly what is wrong.

Comment: hmm... having a hard time visualizing. Can you post an as is, and a should be image?

Comment: @samstar- i don't yet have enough points/credit to post images. may i email?

Comment: we seem to work about the same time...so, how about a chat tomorrow around 9:30AM Eastern US?

Comment: unfortunately i've got a pretty intense work schedule today. i did manage to upload the files so that they can be seen live.. the logo isn't showing up on my end- perhaps you can see it? either way, the right sidebar is supposed to be in a fixed position level with the leftside nav.
http://achenn.site90.net/

Comment: Made the changes. Everything works fine in index.html, however the sidebar is still at the bottom of the page in work.html.. ?

Comment: It appears that you will have to apply these changes to every page that you currently have a sidebar on, because all that I saw had `float:right` which doesn't work with `position:fixed`.

Comment: I applied the changes to the one style.css file that both index.html and work.html read, am I missing something else?

Comment: can you make it live on the link you gave me?

Comment: Firefox's firebug is still showing you have the sidebar floated right.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/zldJd.png

i took a screenshot showing the changes being made on my end. i applied your suggested changes, uploaded to the temp site, opened firebug to examine. i did have to zoom out quite a bit to show the sidebar. 

*i really am so grateful for all of your help. thank you.

Comment: It has been my privilege! So is it fixed?

Comment: unfortunately no, just felt bad for taking up so much of your time.
..do you think my using <sidebar>, <twitter>, etc for tags instead of div class or div id would cause this?

Comment: hey, this is a hobby, and HTML/CSS practice for me, so don't worry about it. It could... definitely more advanced tags require more advanced browsers... Is that HTML5? I am not familiar with that... one way or the other, standard divs would probably make development easier... I won't be around as much during the weekend, but I be back strong Mon. Maybe we can chat then (before SO throws us out....). :)

Comment: I finally figured out my sidebar issue.. I neglected to close a few tags in the <work> section. Once I closed them, the sidebar jumped up to where I wanted it. Thanks again.

Comment: for future reference, validating your HTML would have would have revealed the problem immediately. The validation website is: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I was using the validation tool in Coda- I figured it would have caught that. I'll test out the w3 one next time!